# Substituting values in multivariate polynomial in GAP

Tags: gap

given a polynomial $p(x,y)$ from $\mathbb Z[x,y]$. I want to substitute $x=1$ leaving $y$ as it is. The command `Value(p,[1,y])` does not work. Can you give me a hint?

After that it gets a little more complicated. Let 
$$p(x,y)=x^6+y^6$$
After substituting $x=1$ we have $p(1,y)=1+y^6$. Given a natural number $j$. I want to find all expressions $y^j$ in $p$ and substitute these $y^j$ by $1$ and the others by $0$. In this case (and for $j=6$) we would get $1+1=2$. If $$p(x,y)=x^4y^2+x^2y^6$$
we should get $0+1=1$. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for reading!
edit: Well, it turns out I used the function `Value` wrong. The right code for my problem would be `Value(p,[x,y],[1,y])`. So my first question is solved.

Comment: Please review the tutorial for formatting in latex [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry, I changed it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the so called *external representation* of the polynomial. For example, for $$p(x,y)=x^4y^2+x^2y^6$$ we have:

```
gap> x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");;
gap> y:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"y");;
gap> p:=x^4*y^2+x^2*y^6;
x^2*y^6+x^4*y^2
gap> ExtRepPolynomialRatFun(p);                 
[ [ 1, 4, 2, 2 ], 1, [ 1, 2, 2, 6 ], 1 ]
```

The format of the list returned by the last command is documented in the Section "The Defining Attributes of Rational Functions" of the GAP Reference Manual chapter ["Polynomials and Rational Functions"](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html). It has lists representing monomials in odd positions and corresponding coefficient in even positions. A monomial is represented as a list of the form `[inum,exp,inum,exp,...]` where each `inum` is the number of an indeterminate and `exp` the corresponding exponent. It should be straightforward now to implement the calculation as described in the question - please do not hesitate to ask if you need further hints.

Comment: Thank your very much, I really appreciate your answer. I'll try to implement everything tomorrow.

Comment: Everything worked out, thank you!

Comment: @DominikB.: great, thanks for letting me know!